# Is this a legal if sentance?

Tags: java, bluej

I just started coding and can't get this "Heater" object to work. It just prompts the if else statement "its too hot" when trying to give temp a higher value and it does not stop/ goes below the min temp value when calling the "colder" method. Thanks

```
public class Heater {
    private double temp;
    private double min;
    private double max;
    private double increment;

    public Heater(double min, double max) {
        temp = 15;
        increment = 5;
    }

    public void Warmer() {
        if(temp + increment <= max) {
            temp = temp + increment;
        } else if(temp + increment > max) {
            System.out.println("Too hot");
        }
    }

    public void Colder() {
        if(temp - increment >= min){
            temp = temp - increment;
        } else if (temp - increment < min){
            System.out.println("Too cold");
        }
    }

    public double getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting `min` and `max` in your constructor, so they stay at 0 by default. Try this:

```
public Heater(double min, double max) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    temp = 15;
    increment = 5;
}
```

Comment: Also, consider some test cases. What if someone sets `min` greater than `max`?

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using Caps for method names. Caps are for Class names.
2. You aren't setting `min`. It's at a value of zero.
3. You don't need the `else if` condition - just use `else` instead.

---

```
 public void colder() { // method name, make lower case.
    if(temp - increment >= min){
       temp = temp - increment;
    } else {
       System.out.println("Too cold");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Oh, @Michael Dodd beat me to it.

Comment: You still need the `else` keyword. In that example it will always print `Too Cold`

Comment: Thanks, You're correct, I was too quick to comment the line. I meant to comment between the else and if.